# Python (matplotlib) equivalent of stacked bar chart in R (ggplot)

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

I am looking for an equivalent in python (matplotlib) of the following stacked bar chart created in R (ggplot):

The dummy data (in R) looks like this:

```
seasons <- c("Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall")
feelings <- c("Cold", "Cold", "Cold", "Warm", "Warm", "Cold", "Warm", "Warm", "Warm", "Warm", "Cold", "Cold")
survey <- data.frame(seasons, feelings)
```

In R I can create the chart I am looking for with the following one-liner:

```
ggplot(survey, aes(x=seasons, fill=feelings)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

It looks like this:

[image: stacked bar chart]

How can I create this chart in python (preferably with matplotlib) in an easy and compact way?

I found some (almost) fitting solutions but they were all rather complicated and far away from a one-liner. Or is this not possible in python (matplotlib)?

Comment: Have you gone through this https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html ?

Comment: Yes, but this did not really help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.** Prepare your data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "seasons":["Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall"],
        "feelings":["Cold", "Cold", "Cold", "Warm", "Warm", "Cold", "Warm", "Warm", "Warm", "Warm", "Cold", "Cold"]
    }
)


df_new = df.pivot_table(columns="seasons", index="feelings", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).T.apply(lambda x: x/sum(x), axis=1)
df_new
feelings      Cold      Warm
seasons                     
Fall      0.666667  0.333333
Spring    0.333333  0.666667
Summer    0.000000  1.000000
Winter    1.000000  0.000000
```

**Step 2.** Plot your data

```
ax = df_new.plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5), title="feelings", framealpha=0);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That would indeed create the same plot. But maybe I did not make it clear enough in my question. There is no way in matplotlib (or any other python package) to create a similar plot in a short and easy way (one-liner) as it is in ggplot in R? In other words, is it really necessary to write so much code for such a plot and therefore would you recommend using ggplot/R over python for such a purpose?

Comment: You need to prepare data and plot. This is the shortest way to achieve what you want. 2 lines at least. R and Python different. You should choose what suits you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using seaborn (based on matplotlib and can be further customized with matplotlib calls).

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "seasons":["Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall"],
        "feelings":["Cold", "Cold", "Cold", "Warm", "Warm", "Cold", "Warm", "Warm", "Warm", "Warm", "Cold", "Cold"]
    }
)
sns.histplot(df, x="seasons", hue="feelings", multiple="fill")
```

As a previous R person that now uses mostly python, I had also been searching for an easier way to do this without relying on `plotnine` and instead using plotting libraries more native to the python community.

Hope this helps!

*Packages used:*

- pandas==1.5.2
- seaborn==0.12.2

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wed to matplotlib and really prefer ggplot, then you can just use the `plotnine` library which is a ggplot clone in Python.  The syntax is near identical:

```py
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

survey = pd.DataFrame({
    'seasons': ['Winter', 'Winter', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Spring', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Summer', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Fall', 'Fall'],
    'feelings': ['Cold', 'Cold', 'Cold', 'Warm', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Warm', 'Warm', 'Warm', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Cold'],
})

(
    ggplot(survey, aes(x='seasons', fill='feelings'))
    + geom_bar(position = 'fill')
)
```

As is the output:

[image]